# How to deal with a JSON stored in a row of a very large unpartitioned Hive table

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark SQL (spark 2.1) to read in a hive table.
The schema of the hive table is the following (simplified to the only field that is intesrting related to my problem, the other are useless) :

Body type:Bynary

The body is  a JSON with multiple field and the one I'm interested in is an array. In each index of this array I have another JSON  that contains a date.
My goal is to obtain a dataset filled with all the object of my array that have a date superior to "insert the wanted date".

To do so I use the following code :

```
SparkConfig conf = //set the kryo serializer and tungsten at true

SparkSession ss = //set the conf on the spark session

Dataset<String> dataset = creatMyDatasetWithTheGoodType(SS.SQL("select * from mytable "));

Dataset<String> finalds = dataset.flatmap(json-> 
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> ldate =//i use Jackson to obtain the array of date, this action return a list
For(int i = O; i < ldate.size ; i++) { 
//if date is ok i add it to l
}

Return l.iterator()
});
```

(My code is working on a small dataset I gave it to give an idea of what I was doing)
The problem is that this hive table has like 22 millions lines.
The job turned for 14 hours and didn't finish (I killed it but no error or GC overhead)

I'm running it with yarn-client with 4 executors having 16 go of memory each. The driver has 4 go of memory. 1 core for the executor each.

I used a hdfs dfs -du hiveTableLocationPath and I had like 45 Go as a result.

What can I do to tune my job ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try this UDTF that allows working on [json columns within hive](https://github.com/CyberAgent/hive-jq-udtf)
It is then possible to manipulate large json and fetch needed data in a distributed and optimized way.